# RewriteRule - Check if certain Term in URL exists, if not add it

Tags: ajax, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, search-engine

I am currenctly facing some htaccess/rewriterule issues. (And I am new to this area)

Let's assume we have an url like this: 
http://mypage.at/very/cool

The URL is supposed to look like this (Cause I am using an AJAX-loadedContent which requires this): 
http://mypage.at/#ajx/very/cool

So I would like to add the part '#ajx' to every url which does not already contain it. 
Which means if an url does already look like: http://mypage.at/#ajx/so/pretty then there is no need for changes.

As I am not sure wheter this creates troubles with the GoogleSearchIndex, I would additionally like to know if there is a way to exclude this rule for searchbots.

Thanks for any help.
Ripei

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hah finally after lot's of reading and testing - I got it.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^#ajx
RewriteRule . /\#ajx%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R,NE]
```

This Code works for me... don' ask me why this one is working, to be honest I do not have a clue! But well I am fine with the fact, that it IS working :)

Comment: I probably should add that this breaks my AJAX-loaded Content/Navigation but I am not sure whether this rewrite rule is the cause or the AJAX-Module itself

Comment: I finally resolved it via: JS (cause JS is required for my homepage - anyway): `<script ax:skip='1' type='text/javascript' >
    var l = location, basepath = '/'; 
    if (l.pathname != basepath) l.replace(basepath+'#!ajx'+ l.pathname + (l.search || ''));
</script>
`

Answer (score 1):

Since you reported that this does not work (which is probably because your version of Apache doesn't support Perl-style RegEx):

```
RewriteRule ^(?!#ajx)(.*)$ http://mypage.at/#ajx/$1 [L]
```

I think this should do it:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/#ajx
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://mypage.at/#ajx/$1 [L]
```

**EDIT:** After trying this myself and reading around on the Internet, I'm not sure this is actually possible. A pound sign (#) is not a legal part of a URL. This answer comes close, but I'm going to have to leave this to somebody who knows more to say whether this can even be done the way @Ripei asked for.

Comment: I am afraid but this is not working for me. (I did changed your typo at the beginngin ajk->ajx) I also tested it here: http://martinmelin.se/rewrite-rule-tester/

Comment: Apparently negative lookarounds (the `(?!)` part) aren't supported by older versions of Apache, so that might be why it isn't working. I'll see what I can figure out later today.

Comment: See my updated answer. It's very similar to Dave's answer, but with a few small differences.

Comment: By the way, that mod_rewrite tester seems handy, but from what I can tell, it doesn't support the exclamation point for **not**, which makes it impossible to test my answer with it.

Comment: Thanks for the new suggestion: But also when I try to add the part "ajx" without the # - it's also not wokring because i would still get the "/ajx" part about 20times. (As said beyond Dave's post)

Answer (score 0):

Something like this might work:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/#ajx
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://%{SERVER_NAME}/#ajx$1 [R,L]
```

Comment: I don't believe the REQUEST_URI starts with a slash. So, instead: `!^#ajx` and then `#ajx/$1` at the end of the second line. Also, I would do `RewriteRule ^(.*)$` just to be safe.

Comment: Just tried it with the necessary changes from Compeek, but now I get a url like: http://mypage.at/%23ajx/%23ajx/%23ajx/%23ajx/%23ajx/%23ajx/%23ajx/%23ajx/%23ajx/%23ajx/%23ajx/%23ajx/%23ajx/%23ajx/%23ajx/%23ajx/%23ajx/%23ajx/%23ajx/%23ajx/some/further/path

Comment: Are you including the [L] flag? I would recommend using Compeek's other answer as this answer was actually from a httpd.conf file which uses the slashes whereas .htaccess files do not.

Comment: yes i did. but it's still not working for me. thx for the response.

Comment: I think I was wrong. The slash is indeed included. I have no idea why this isn't working.

Comment: I would suggest turning on the rewrite log using: RewriteLog logs/rwlog.log
RewriteLogLevel 9. This may help determine why it is not matching.